# Eclipse doesnt'start correctly anymore, can't import libraries and run projects

Tags: java, eclipse

Today i was starting my eclipse and i saw this:

[image]

If i click it away, my jboss is complaining: "An internal error occurred during: "Download quickstarts list".org/jboss/dmr/ModelNode

I can't even import any libraries anymore, the "+" sign is a red square now.

What is happening here? Any suggestions, what i can do to bring eclipse to worl? I have completely deleted and reinstalled my Eclipse and created a new workspace, but it doesn't help. Is there a directory, which i need do delete?

Comment: check java_home ambient variable, check the compliance level under windows>preferences

Answer (score 0):

Generics is supported in Java 1.5 and higher.

It is clearly displaying that generics are supported in Java 1.5 and higher in your screen shot.
So please change the jre ore Jdk version to 1.5 or higher in your build path to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

check your project buildpath..seems like jre in classpath is incorrect or not working..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers. There seemed to be some issues with my system (virus or something else), because other system components where also influenced. I have set it up new and then it worked fine.